# Extract values from List of Dictionaries using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple list of dictionaries as below.

```
data_records = [{'client': 'AAA',
                    'keys': ['k001', 'k002'],
                    'server_name': 'server00',
                    'db_name': 'db-aaa',
                    },
                   {'client': 'BBB',
                    'keys': [],
                    'server_name': 'server01',
                    'db_name': 'db-bbb',
                    },
                   {'client': 'CCC',
                    'keys': ['k003', 'k004', 'k005', 'k006'],
                    'server_name': 'server02',
                    'db_name': 'db-ccc',
                    },
                   ]
```

I'm trying to write a function that takes any of the keys 'client' or 'keys' and extracts the appropriate 'server_name' and 'db_name' from the above list.

```
def get_data()
"""
Look up the server_name and db_name based on the given 'key' or 'client' and return Tuple of strings (server_name, db_name)
"""


get_data(client_id='AAA')
get_data(session_key='k004')
get_data(session_key='')
```

Appreciate if anyone can show me how to write this 
get_data() function in a simple way. Thanks!

Comment: Is this something you're doing often and for large data sets? If so, the answers below are all `O(n)`, which isn't necessarily the fastest way of handling this. (It can be reduced to `O(1)` if you keep two additional hashmaps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to loop over the list of records and checks the values of them. Searching by the client is slightly different than searching by the keys. You should also account for a search value returning multiple values. Try something like this:

```
def get_data(client_id=None, session_key=None):
    # validate inputs
    if client_id is None and session_key is None:
        raise Exception("One search parameter must be supplied")

    if client_id is not None and session_key is not None:
        raise Exception("Only one search parameter can be supplied")

    # container to store all matches
    results = []

    # the client_id case
    if client_id is not None:
        for data_record in data_records:
            if client_id == data_record['client']:
                results.append(
                    (data_record['server_name'], data_record['db_name'])
                )

    # the session_key case
    if session_key is not None:
        for data_record in data_records:
            if session_key in data_record['keys']:
                results.append(
                    (data_record['server_name'], data_record['db_name'])
                )

    return results
```

If you wanted to combine both searches then you could also do something like this:

```
def get_data(client_id=None, session_key=None):
    # validate inputs
    if client_id is None and session_key is None:
        raise Exception("At least one search parameter must be supplied")

    # container to store all matches
    results = []

    # If a filter is active and doesn't match, 
    # skip the record and don't add the value
    for data_record in data_records:
        if client_id is not None: 
            if client_id != data_record['client']:
                continue

        if session_key is not None: 
            if session_key not in data_record['keys']:
                continue

        results.append(
            (data_record['server_name'], data_record['db_name'])
        )

    return results
```

Just for fun, doing this all in a list comprehension:

```
def get_data(client_id=None, session_key=None):
    # validate inputs
    if client_id is None and session_key is None:
        raise Exception("At least one search parameter must be supplied")

    return [
        (record['server_name'], record['db_name'])
        for record in data_records
        if (client_id is None or client_id == record['client'])
        and (session_key is None or session_key in record['keys'])
    ]
```

If you want to allow the search params to be empty and just return the first value, then you could also do this:

```
def get_data(client_id=None, session_key=None):
    results = (
        (record['server_name'], record['db_name'])
        for record in data_records
        if (client_id is None or client_id == record['client'])
        and (session_key is None or session_key in record['keys'])
    )
    return next(results, None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts and multiple ways. But, can you show the o/p for each of these methods? I'm getting errors

Comment: @user11899229 Ah, I did have two errors, I updated the answer.

Comment: Great...Thanks a lot...it's working now

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_info(data, *, client_id=None, session_key=None):
    if client_id is not None:
        d = next((x for x in data if x['client'] == client_id), None)
    elif session_key is not None:
        d = next((x for x in data if session_key in x['keys']), None)
    else:
        raise ValueError('No selector provided')

    if d is None:
        raise ValueError('Could not find')

    return d['server_name'], d['db_name']
```

Comment: Thanks...But, it's throwing an error something related to 'Generator expression'.

Comment: @user11899229 Whoops, I forgot a parenthesis!

Comment: Great...Thanks a lot...it's working now

Answer (score 1):

```
data_records = [{'client': 'AAA',
                    'keys': ['k001', 'k002'],
                    'server_name': 'server00',
                    'db_name': 'db-aaa',
                    },
                   {'client': 'BBB',
                    'keys': [],
                    'server_name': 'server01',
                    'db_name': 'db-bbb',
                    },
                   {'client': 'CCC',
                    'keys': ['k003', 'k004', 'k005', 'k006'],
                    'server_name': 'server02',
                    'db_name': 'db-ccc',
                    },
                   ]

def get_data(client_id=None, session_key=None):
    if client_id:
        for d in data_records:
            if d['client'] ==  client_id:
                return (d['server_name'], d['db_name'])
    if session_key:
        for d in data_records:
            if session_key in d['keys']:
                return (d['server_name'], d['db_name'])

print(get_data(client_id='AAA'))
print(get_data(session_key='k004'))
print(get_data(session_key=''))
```

Output

```
('server00', 'db-aaa')
('server02', 'db-ccc')
None
```

Comment: Thanks!...This code looks simple and it fits the bill...